# How can I display the IP address of an interface?

Tags: networking, bash, ip, shell, ip-address

If I want to display the IP address that is assigned to eth1, how can I do this in Bash?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this (Linux)

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth1 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2| cut -d' ' -f1
```

or this (Linux)

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | awk -F ' *|:' '/inet addr/{print $4}'
```

or this (*BSD)

```
ifconfig bge0 | grep 'inet' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

or this (Solaris 10)

```
ifconfig e1000g0 | awk '/inet / {print $6}'
```

Obviously change the interface name to match the one you want to get the information from.

Comment: worked also ifconfig eth1| awk -F ' *|:' '/inet addr/{print $4}'

Comment: On *BSD systems the ifconfig output is a bit different - `ifconfig bge0 | grep 'inet' | cut -d' ' -f2` will work (substitute your appropriate interface name in place of `bge0`, obviously)

Comment: ip addr show eth1| grep inet|awk '{print $2;}'

Answer (score 26):

As @Manuel mentioned, `ifconfig` is out of date, and `ip` is the recommended approach going forward.

`ip -f inet addr show eth1`

and to use @bleater's sed or @Jason H.'s awk to filter the output (depending on if you want the mask)

`ip -f inet addr show eth1 | sed -En -e 's/.*inet ([0-9.]+).*/\1/p'`

`ip -f inet addr show eth1 | awk '/inet / {print $2}'`

Comment: This answer is also fit if you need only IPv4-addresses.

Comment: `ip -f inet6 addr show eth1 | sed -En -e 's/.*inet6 ([0-9a-fA-F:]+).*/\1/p'` for ipv6

Comment: `ip -f inet addr show lo | awk '/inet / {print $2}'` gives me `127.0.0.1/8`, not the desired `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: ```ip -4 -o addr show eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d "/" -f 1``` if you don't like sed

Answer (score 16):

On a Linux system:

```
hostname --all-ip-addresses
```

will give you only the IP address.

On a Solaris system use:

```
ifconfig e1000g0 | awk '/inet / {print $2}'
```

Comment: From the hostname(1) man page: `Avoid using this option; use hostname --all-ip-addresses instead.`

Comment: amazing tips loving it thank you very much

Answer (score 11):

To obtain both IPv4 and IPv6 IP addresses with netmasks just try:

```
ip a l eth1 | awk '/inet/ {print $2}'
```

Or without netmasks (can't imagine why you need an IP address without a mask):

```
ip a l eth1 | awk '/inet/ {print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1
```

Comment: "can't imagine why you need an IP address without a mask" 

Simple, there's very few clients that support it. You can't ping 1.1.1.1/32.  https://1.1.1.1/32 would return a 404. You can't point an A record to it, nor insert it into a reverse proxy config, nor tunnel to it, nor put it into /etc/hosts.

Comment: @copycat What is the need to ping your own interface?

Comment: "l" stands for list (not documented in inline help (iproute2 version  5.5.0), only documented in manpage).

Comment: @red0ct for anyone writing a script where the IP needs to be an input for example. Pairing an IP to a Mac address, the cidr range is already known by the system that wants this information. Passing the cidr range would require more processing somewhere down the line, so it's just a matter of where you want to do that work.

Answer (score 9):

A better way: get ip adress from command "ip", because "ifconfig" is out of date. Otherwise you will get a problem on using "ifconfig", because the output of ifconfig is language dependend.

I use this command to get all IPs (IPv4):

```
ip addr show | grep -o "inet [0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" | grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"
```

Comment: `ifconfig` has the advantage of existing on systems that aren't Linux...

Comment: NB: This is only about IPv4-addresses.

Answer (score 6):

Works well on various linux:

```
ip -brief address show eth0 | awk '{print $3}' | awk -F/ '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe this will help

```
ifconfig eth1
```

Answer (score 2):

on Ubuntu 20.04

$ sudo apt install moreutils
$ ifdata -pa eth0
192.168.1.152

Answer (score 2):

On recent OS and tools versions, using JSON interface should work too, e.g.:

```
 ip -json addr show docker0 \
 | jq '.[].addr_info[] | select(.family == "inet").local'
```

Which yields on my machine:

```
 "172.17.0.1"
```

Comment: This is actually my favorite, thanks!

Comment: To make it run from a subprocess:

`local_ips = subprocess.check_output(["ip -json addr show eth0  | jq -r '.[].addr_info[] | select(.family == \"inet\" | @sh).local'"], shell=True, encoding='utf8')`

Answer (score 1):

`ip addr show dev eth0` if you want to see all addresses for one interface

Comment: Welcome to the server fault community. How does this answer differ from previously given answers?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @JohnK.N. The previously given answers have a lot of grep, sed and awk that felt unnecessary for answering the simple question asked. The accepted answer uses a deprecated command. If you feel my answer isn't valid or helpful I can certainly remove it.

Answer (score 0):

One liner with sed:

```
ifconfig wlan0 | sed -En -e 's/.*inet ([0-9.]+).*/\1/p'
```

Replace wlan0 with the desired interface.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted answer on **CentOS 7**, but it does not work.

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet ' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d" " -f3
```

worked for me, in case someone else is also running into the same problem.

Comment: As mentioned by @Manuel and @pstanton, `ifconfig` should be avoided. It's actually removed in some newer  distros. This is probably why your answer was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
ip r s | awk '/eth0/ {print $7}'
```

will print, for example: `192.168.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS I use `ipconfig getifaddr <interface-name>`
The command is listed under the `BSD System Manager's Manual`.